# With Breeze.js, Is There a Way to Create an Uninitialized Entity and Bind It to an "Add New" Form?

Tags: breeze

So far all of the examples that I have seen for adding a new entity would go through the following steps:

1. Create a bunch of "new-" variables that get bound to on screen controls.
2. When user wants to submit the addition, created an uninitialized new entity.
3. Copy "new-" variables to each member of the new entity one by one.
4. Push the new entity onto the manager's entity list.
5. Save changes.
6. Clear all of the "new-" variables.

This is problematic for many reasons. These "new-" variables have to be maintained in addition to the on screen controls. When server side entities change, they must be changed manually. This is time consuming and error prone.

I would like to be able to create an uninitialized new entity first, and bind it to on screen controls immediately, without using those variables with the "new-" prefix. When user wants to submit the addition, push the new entity onto the manager's entity list, and then save changes. Then bind the on screen controls immediately to a newly created uninitialized entity.

This way, we can avoid dealing with individual entity attributes in the view model, which would produce more robust code, and save a lot of time.

Right now, the metadata for creating a new entity is not available when the document becomes ready. If I download it, I have to deal with asynchronous completion before I can bind a new entity to on screen controls.

So my question is: is there a way to have the metadata downloaded with the initial HTML download so that I can create an uninitialized new entity without waiting, and bind it to on screen HTML controls immediately?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what means uninitialized new entity, but yes - you can create for example a new car like this:

```
var newCar = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Car").createEntity();
manager.addEntity(newCar);
```

Bind your controls to the newCar. To save the changes call `manager.saveChanges();`, to cancel call `manager.rejectChanges();`

To be able to work with entities breeze needs metadata. If you want, you can send metadata with the page itself. You can then use manager.importMetadata() to import it into the manager. The only problem is that you will need to write a small app that will generate the metadata string (during build) so that later it can be passed to importMetadata(). Take a look at [MetadataStore Class API](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hit enter to create a new line, only got my comment sent prematurely. Indeed the key is the metadata. The question is really whether we can avoid writing that "small app" as you stated in your reply. Breeze can easily provide a helper class like this to place the metadata in the HTML:  @BreezeHelper.DeclareEntityType("Car"). Would anyone know if there is such a thing already?

Comment: Interesting idea. I would not specify a type as in your ex. because types are often interrelated. But I can imagine wanting the metadata to ship with the page either embedded or perhaps as a standalone JavaScript file. I would call `MetadataStore.exportMetadata()` to generate the string representation of the metadata. Note that this string **could not be generated on the server**; it includes client-side fixup. And of course you'd have to remember to run the generator after changes. IdeaBlade could write a helper or the community can write it. Add it to User Voice; we'll see who votes for it.

Comment: Btw, @XiaodongTan, how hard is it to stall the UI until your call to `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata(serviceName)` returns? I often have asynchronous initialization logic that must complete before I bind anything to the screen. Metadata is just one such chunk of logic. Happy to show you a pattern for this if it would be helpful.

Comment: @XiaodongTan, it looks like you want to avoid async stuff completely. It's better to start writing the app the "asynchronous way" right from the start, like Ward suggests. [Q.js readme](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) was very helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I am not looking for an synchronous solution. The question only concerns data initialization/creation. Without auto generated metadata, in a form that is supposed to submit an brand new entity, one would have to declare view model in javascript by hand. That would not be very productive, I am afraid.